# As3 remove current clip if playing

Tags: actionscript-3, removechild

I have buttons that add movie clips to stage and wont go away when other button is clicked to add another.  I've seen similar issues posted but none of the answers worked for me.

```
btnBlue.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseOverHandler1);
function fl_MouseOverHandler1(evt: MouseEvent): void {
    var ballBlue: BallBlue = new BallBlue;
    addChild(ballBlue);
    addChildAt(ballBlue, 0);
    ballBlue.x = 100; //sets the x position
    ballBlue.y = 100; //sets the y position}

    function onClick(evt:MouseEvent):void {  */to remove clip if one is playing
        removeChildAt(0)
    }
}

btnRed.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseOverHandler2);
function fl_MouseOverHandler2(evt: MouseEvent): void {
    var ballRed: BallRed = new BallRed;
    addChild(ballRed);
    addChildAt(ballRed, 0);
    ballRed.x = 100; //sets the x position
    ballRed.y = 100; //sets the y position}
    parent.BallBlue.removeMovieClip(); 

    function onClick(evt:MouseEvent):void {  */to remove clip if one is playing
        removeChildAt(0)
    }
}
```

Comment: Define `var ballBlue:BallBlue;` outside that function, so that it's accessible by the second function with `removeChild(ballBlue);`. Other option is to save reference of the ball when you create it (f.ex. push it in Array). Variables you define inside a function are accessible only inside the very same function if you don't have any reference to them.

Comment: You are also having a function inside a function, which is not what you need and which wont work like you intented it to work. Also, you are using `addChild` twice per ball, but the first one (`addChild(ballBlue);`) does the job I'm sure.

Comment: There are several places your code obviously goes wrong, still you should start with describing the intended result, because there's no telling what are you trying to do once you remove scripts from your post.

Comment: Please clarify the expected behavior.   I'm going to guess that when you click the blue button, that if I blue ball already exists you want to remove it, then add a new blue ball?

Comment: OR, when you click a blue ball, you want that ball to remove itself.    Or you want there to only ever be 1 color of ball on the screen, so that if you click the blue button it removes any red balls prior to creating a blue ball?

Answer (score 0):

```
btnBlue.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnBlue_clickHandler);
btnRed.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnRed_clickHandler);

var ballBlue: BallBlue = new BallBlue();
var ballRed: BallRed = new BallRed();

function btnBlue_clickHandler(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    removeAllBalls();
    addChild(ballBlue);
    ballBlue.x = 100; //sets the x position
    ballBlue.y = 100; //sets the y position
}

function btnRed_clickHandler(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    removeAllBalls();
    addChild(ballRed);
    ballRed.x = 100; //sets the x position
    ballRed.y = 100; //sets the y position
}

function removeAllBalls():void {
    if (contains(ballBlue))
    {
        removeChild(ballBlue);
    }
    if (contains(ballRed))
    {
        removeChild(ballRed);
    }
}
```